# Android Studio: How do I scale the Android Emulator appropriately on Windows when DPI scaling is enabled?

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

When I try to run the Android Emulator on Windows (DPI scaling of 150%, resolution of 3840x2160), I end up with an emulator window with a viewport that isn't scaled correctly. The clicks still rely on the full window size (eg: to press the Home button, I have to click toward the bottom of the window).

Anyone run into this behavior?
[image: mismatched scaling]